# Create production release - Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-keystore

I'm Creating New App bundle for my New App.
There is little confusion over there like upload_key is just another keystore created using same process?

Need this setup Export and upload a key from Java keystore

If I'm uploading fresh release then what steps should follow properly.

What I'm doing wrong here

Step 1 - Generated Signed Bundle(which I'm Uploading on Play Console) with new keystore.jsk and using that keystore and alias I have created output.zip with that given command

Step 2 - Generated New Key Store just called upload_key with different information. and created certificate for it. and uploaded it. As Play Store Required

but not able to upload app it won't allow me to upload

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:

Comment: Why step 2? You should use the key from step 1.

Comment: I did face the same problem did you fixed?